# Can we use IF condition inside the for loop in batch scripting?

Tags: batch-file, scripting, windows-scripting

```
set STR1= FINISHED

for /f "tokens=4,* delims=:" %a in (filename.txt) do (if %b == %STR1% (echo "SUCCESS") else (echo %b))
```

I am using the above code , but unable to loop through ,it's simply doing echo %b.

filename.txt :

12:38:32,249 INFO  [SoapUIRunner] Finished running SoapUI testcase [Couple Order], time taken: 14124ms, status: FAILED

12:38:34,441 INFO  [SoapUIRunner] Finished running SoapUI testcase [Ping], time taken: 2136ms, status: FINISHED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ducking crossfire]

Now - not so fast, pardners....

As written, the code *should* execute

```
(if  FINISHED == FINISHED (echo "SUCCESS" )  else (echo  FINISHED ) )
```

but reports

```
 FINISHED
```

Now the unwary would think that it's not acting logically - but unbelievably, it is.

The point is that the comparison is performed using the token stream `if` `%b` `==` `FINISHED`. The leading space in `%str1%` is eaten by the parser as it's an optional separator. The processing then decides ***correctly*** that the contents of `%b` is not the same as `FINISHED` as `%b` contains a leading space.

Cure to code as posted:

```
for /f "tokens=4,* delims=:" %a in (filename.txt) do (if "%b" == "%STR1%" (echo "SUCCESS") else (echo %b))
```

where the quotes teach `cmd` to not regard the leading space in `str1` as a separator.

Of course, if this was a line in a batch file as it should be to overcome the perpetual-retyping problem, then the metavariables should, indeed have their `%`s doubled.

Tips : Use `set "var1=data"` for setting values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. In comparisons, use `if "thing1" == "thing2" ...` to avoid problems caused by spaces in `thing1/2`.